# UFuncTypeError When adding two datetime dates

Tags: python, numpy, datetime

I am trying to read some date info from Excel using `openpyxl` which returns them as `datetime.datetime`.  I need to resample the data and then plot the resampled times using `matplotlib`.  I would like an array of dates starting at `tmin`, incremented by 30.0 days.
The code stub is

```
import numpy as np
import datetime

vals = [
datetime.date.fromisoformat('2004-06-01'),
datetime.date.fromisoformat('2004-07-01'),
datetime.date.fromisoformat('2004-08-01'),
datetime.date.fromisoformat('2004-09-01'),
datetime.date.fromisoformat('2004-10-01'),
datetime.date.fromisoformat('2004-11-01')]

xtim = np.array(vals)
tmin = np.min(xtim)

ytim = np.arange(0.0, 150.0, 30.0)
tnew = tmin + ytim.astype('timedelta64[D]')
```

Unfortunately, this gives me the error message

```
UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' cannot use operands with types dtype('O') and dtype('<m8[D]')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap `tmin` in an array with 'datetime64' type:

```
np.array(tmin, dtype='datetime64') + ytim.astype('timedelta64[D]')
```

output: `array(['2004-06-01', '2004-07-01', '2004-07-31', '2004-08-30', '2004-09-29'], dtype='datetime64[D]')`

Comment: Thanks @mozway - this is the sort of thing that really confuses me.  I assumed (obviously wrongly) that `xtim = np.array(vals)` automatically did the conversion to `np.datetime64`

Comment: @PetGriffin no worries ;) A tip, when you have a reference to `dtype('O')` in the error, then usually something is wrong with the array type

Answer (score 0):

To add 30 days I'd suggest using `datetime.timedelta(days=30)`.
For example as:

```
import numpy as np
import datetime

vals = [
    datetime.date.fromisoformat('2004-06-01'),
    datetime.date.fromisoformat('2004-07-01'),
    datetime.date.fromisoformat('2004-08-01'),
    datetime.date.fromisoformat('2004-09-01'),
    datetime.date.fromisoformat('2004-10-01'),
    datetime.date.fromisoformat('2004-11-01')]

xtim = np.array(vals)
tmin = np.min(xtim)


t_new=[tmin+datetime.timedelta(days=i) for i in np.arange(0.0, 150.0, 30.0)]
```